# Access a assign delegate property from Objective-C Block? (iOS)

Tags: ios, ios4, objective-c-blocks

Is it ok to access a delegate property from an Block?

```
@interface TheObject : NSObject
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SomeDelegate> delegate;

@synthesize delegate

- (void) someMethod {
  [someObject doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *)someArray {
      [self.delegate otherMethod:someArray];   
 }];
}
```

What happens if the delegate is nilled (from the dealloc method in the object that has also set the delegate) before the completion handler is called?
Could it be a memory bug?
I don't know how to use `__block` for properties...

Answer from below:

If the delegate is nilled from the object which is the delegate on the dealloc call, everything is fine.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) TheObject theObject;

@synthezise theObject = _theObject;

- (void) thatMethod {
  self.theObject = [[TheObject alloc] init] autorelease];
  _theObject.delegate = self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
  _theObject.delegate = nil;
  self.theObject = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, if your `delegate` is deallocated before the block is executed, then it would access garbage, since the block is an `assign` property and the block retains `self` rather than the `delegate` since you access it by reference.

However, since you've set it up so that `self.delegate` gets nilled if `delegate` is deallocated, you won't have that problem. Instead, if your `delegate` were deallocated, then in your code you'd just be sending the `otherMethod:` method to `nil`, which would do nothing, but also cause no errors.

If you want the method to definitely be sent to your `delegate`, the solution is to access it by value instead of reference:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    id <SomeDelegate> delegateForBlock = self.delegate;
    [someObject doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *)someArray {
        [delegateForBlock otherMethod:someArray];   
    }];
}
```

That way `delegateForBlock` will be a pointer to the same object as `self.delegate` (at the time you execute `someMethod:`), and it will be retained.

To find out more about how this works, check out [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1).

Comment: any idea how to solve this problem?
And: If the delegate object is deallocated the delegate ivar is nilled from this object in the dealloc. Also in the block?

Comment: Okay, see updated answer. Also, you should edit your question top put in the bit about how you've set up the pointer to be nilled, since it makes a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the delegate is deallocated, you will be accessing a garbage value which will result in `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

You could either do

```
id <SomeDelegate> dlg = self.delegate
[someObject doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *)someArray {
  [dlg otherMethod:someArray];   
}];
```

or access the ivar directly, so that the block retains it

```
[someObject doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *)someArray {
  [delegate otherMethod:someArray];   
}];
```

Comment: Better check your facts... "If you access an instance variable by value, the variable is retained."

Comment: I made a trivial edit to your post so I could un-downvote it. I seriously hope you're not the one who downvoted my answer, unless you thought there was something wrong with it (in which case it would be great if you could comment on it).